# How can I include metabox content when searching on Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I have a Wordpress website with a catalog of products. Each product has a UPC/SKU (identification number) declared with a custom metabox like this:

```
if(!class_exists('product_metabox') && class_exists('CCM_METABOX')){
class product_metabox extends CCM_METABOX{
    function __construct() {
        $metabox_data = array(
            'title'         => __('Product Data'),
            'post_type'     => array('product'),
            'fields'        => array(
                array(
                    'id'            => 'upc',
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'label'         => __('UPC/SKU'),
                ),
            ),
        );
        parent::__construct('product_metabox', $metabox_data);
    }
}

$product_metabox = new product_metabox();
$product_metabox->init();
```

I add a filter to search only on products and not search on blog/posts from the same webpage, the filter is:

```
function searchfilter($query) {
if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
    $query->set('post_type',array('product'));
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
```

How can I include products in the results when search by ID/SKU metabox? For example, I have a "White Wallet" with a UPC "CM-5674", if I search "Wallet" the results display the White Wallet, but if I type CM-5674 (UPC) it doesn´t show that product.

Comment: What is the name of the post meta where the SKU is stored?